# What pattern am I using to store/retrieve data?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

In my `Controller` I often have a need to write code that stores or retrieves various data, usually from the same data table.

What I usually do is this:

```
class Controller
{
    function saveAction()
    {
        $data = $this->pattern->retrieve();

        $output = $this->process($data);

        $this->pattern->save($output);
    }
}

class Pattern
{
    function retrieve()
    {
        //in my case using ORM EntityManager
        return $em->find(...);
    }

    function save(array $data)
    {
        $object = $data['object'];
        $em->persist($object);
    }

}
```

What type of pattern is this?

Comment: Looks like a `Repository`.

Comment: Registry Design Pattern?

Comment: Thanks.  I was undecided between `DAO` and `Repository`.  Registry pattern is probably too narrow for my scope.  I tend to use the pattern for all kinds of operations, not strictly constrained to keeping track of one thing..  i.e. I may retrieve some new data, run some things, request some specific data, etc.in my case these will be line item object, stores position numbers for each, to indicate relative ordering to each other, and I can use the Pattern to reorder (swap) line item records via changing their position values in object/db.

Comment: Question: .. what makes it more of a `Repository` rather than `DAO`?

Comment: Question: .. what makes it more of a `Repository` rather than `DAO`?  Will it matter if I use/access only a single actual DB table per class, or if I use multiple tables per `Pattern` method?